# Mapping twice to sort by category

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently mapping some data from my database, my Mongoose schema is:

```
const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    category: String,
    name: String,
    image: String


})
```

Here is my server.js:

```
app.post('/api', async (req, res) => {
    Item.find(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        } else {
            res.send(result)
        }
    })
})
```

In my React Home.js component I have the following code which displays all the information from my database correctly:

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            {getBasic.data.map(({ category, image, name, _id }, i) => {

                return (
                    <div>
                        <p>{i}</p>
                        <Link to={`/details/${_id}`} state={{ image: image, name: { name }, _id: { _id } }}>
                            <p>{name}</p>
                            <img src={image} />
                            <p>{_id}</p>
                            <p>{category}</p>
                        </Link>
                    </div>

                );
            })}

        </div>
```

Now the issue I am running into, is I wanted to sort each of the mapped contents by their `category`, as in all of the `Hats` category will go into the same div being flexed, left to right, and all the `Pants` category will go into a new div underneath, etc.

One way I thought of doing this was just by mapping twice, like mapping for a category, then mapping for everything else. I have it set up generally but not sure exactly how to put it in code, this is what I have:

```
 {getBasic.data.map(({ category }, j) => {


                    return (


                        <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                            {getBasic.data.map(({image, name, _id }, i) => {


                                return (
                                    <div>
                                        <p>{i}</p>
                                        <Link to={`/details/${_id}`} state={{ image: image, name: { name }, _id: { _id } }}>
                                            <p>{name}</p>
                                            <img src={image} />
                                            <p>{_id}</p>
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>

                                );
                            })}

                        </div>
                    )

                })}
```

I do not know what to add to the above code so that regardless of how many categories there are it will work. The only way I could think of is adding like `if (category == 'Hats')` however I would have to do this for every single category this wouldn't be optimal nor scalable. I feel like there should be an easier and better way to implement this but I have been staring at it for 1.5 days and am still not sure.

Here is the full code for Home.js:

```
function Home() {

    const [getBasic, setGetBasic] = useState()
    const [sampleState, setSampleState] = useState(21)

    const [Item, setItem] = useState({
        name: '',
        data: '',
        category: ''
    })


    function handleChange(event) {
        let { name, value } = event.target;
        setItem(prevInput => {
            return (
                {
                    ...prevInput,
                    [name]: value,
                }
            );
        });
        // console.log(Item);
    }


    const getBasicFunc = async () => {


        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api')
            .catch(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            })
            .then(result => setGetBasic(result))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getBasicFunc()
    }, [])

    if (getBasic) {

        return (



            <>
                <Header />

                <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    {console.log(getBasic)}
                    <h1>Home</h1>
                    <input onChange={handleChange} name="name" value={Item.name} placeholder="name" />
                    <input onChange={handleChange} name="data" value={Item.data} placeholder="data" />
                    <input onChange={handleChange} name="category" value={Item.category} placeholder="category" />
                    <button onClick={addItem}>Submit</button>
                </div>

                {getBasic.data.map(({ category }, j) => {


                    return (


                        <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                            {getBasic.data.map(({ category, image, name, _id }, i) => {


                                return (
                                    <div>
                                        <p>{i}</p>
                                        <Link to={`/details/${_id}`} state={{ image: image, name: { name }, _id: { _id } }}>
                                            <p>{name}</p>
                                            <img src={image} />
                                            <p>{_id}</p>
                                            <p>{category}</p>
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>

                                );
                            })}

                        </div>
                    )

                })}

            </>


        )
    }
    else {
        return (
            <>
                <Header />
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <h1>Home</h1>
                    <input onChange={handleChange} name="name" value={Item.name} placeholder="name" />
                    <input onChange={handleChange} name="data" value={Item.data} placeholder="data" />
                    <input onChange={handleChange} name="category" value={Item.category} placeholder="category" />
                    <button onClick={addItem}>Submit</button>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

### Update

In the comments it was suggested to sort on the backend thus my server.js now looks like:

```
   Item.find({}).sort('category').exec(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send('error')
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.send(result)
        }
    })
```

Now just trying to get the one div full of `Hats` category to end once the sort gets to `Pants` category as then they would be structured so that each category is a separate row.

### Update 2

I am still stuck on having different flexed divs for each category. The problems seems to be the place where I define the `display: flex` is above where my `getBasic.data.map` starts, thus this is the div with the correct flex. I almost want to do the following:

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex' }} className={category}>
                    {getBasic.data.map(({ category, image, name, _id }, i) => {


                        return (
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <p>{i}</p>
                                    <Link to={`/details/${_id}`} state={{ image: image, name: { name }, _id: { _id } }}>
                                        <p>{name}</p>
                                        <img src={image} />
                                        <p>{_id}</p>
                                        <p>{category}</p>
                                    </Link>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        )
                    })}

                </div>
```

Of course with the above the `className={category}` is above where category gets defined, but I think if I could rearrange this somehow it would give the desired outcome of each horizontal div being belonging to only one category.

### Update 3

To be as clear as possible I am looking for an outcome that would give the same result as the following :

```
                <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                    {getBasic.data.map(({ category, image, name, _id }, i) => {

                        if (category == 'Pants') {
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>{i}</p>
                                        <Link to={`/details/${_id}`} state={{ image: image, name: { name }, _id: { _id } }}>
                                            <p>{name}</p>
                                            <img src={image} />
                                            <p>{_id}</p>
                                            <p>{category}</p>
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            )
                        }
                    })}

                </div>

                <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                    {getBasic.data.map(({ category, image, name, _id }, i) => {


                        if (category == 'Hats') {
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>{i}</p>
                                        <Link to={`/details/${_id}`} state={{ image: image, name: { name }, _id: { _id } }}>
                                            <p>{name}</p>
                                            <img src={image} />
                                            <p>{_id}</p>
                                            <p>{category}</p>
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            )
                        }
                    })}

                </div>
```

The difference is I am looking for a scalable solution so that if I have more than two categories, say for example I add `coats` as a category, then all the coats would be in the next div without me adding another div with an if statement of `if (category == coats)`.

Comment: Why don't you sort in server.js `Item.find({}).sort('category').exec(function (err, result) { ...` ? This way you get the data sorted and you could then map over it and split easily into categories.

Comment: I just tried `Item.sort('category').find(function (err, result) { ` and got the error `Item.sort is not a function` I thought it might work if I just tried sorting the result: `res.send(result.sort('category'))` which ended up getting `TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or undefined`. Thinking the first way could work if I rewrite it, gonna try a few things.

Comment: Ah okay so i got it working, couldn't tell if you updated your comment or I missread it, but that makes sense now and the data I get sorted by category. I am wondering for the second part of the question, how could I get a new div for each new category? Ie line breaks when no more `Hats` to form the next parallel flexed div underneath?

Comment: Do you still need help displaying the categories into seperate divs?

Comment: yes I do, was unable to work on it more last night,  looking at it this morning

Comment: you really should not send the error back

Comment: changed to `console.log(err) res.send('error')` for now, mostly just focusing on the div issue for now however though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var array = [
    {
      category: "hats",
      name: "hat1"
    },
    {
      category: "Pants",
      name: "pants2"
    },
    {
      category: "hats",
      name: "hat2"
    },
    {
      category: "Pants",
      name: "pants1"
    }
  ];

  var arrayofarray = Object.values(
    array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      acc[cur["category"]] = [...(acc[cur["category"]] || []), cur];
      return acc;
    }, {})
  );

  return (
    <>
      {arrayofarray.map((category) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {category.map(({ category, image, name, _id }, i) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <p>
                    {i} {name} {category}
                  </p>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

So i created a test project see sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-lovelace-uw7hen?file=/src/App.js

I think it does what you require, so what I did was create an array of arrays based on the category and then map over the array of arrays, this will get you the result you need.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, I confused myself with my own css. This is the solution I was looking for, thank you very much.